# Why is mypartial.ejs not showing?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, partials

I am trying to learn node.js with the help the book "Get programming with node.js" by Jonathan Wrexler. In chapter 10 the use of partials is explained very briefly and I am not getting it to work.

I made a `nav.ejs` in the `partials`-folder that looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

The `layout.ejs`-example in the book looks like this:

```
  <body>
    <header>Header</header>
    <nav>
      <% include partials/nav %>
    </nav>
    <%- body %>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </body>
```

But this gives me a syntax-error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in C:\node-projects\wandelverhalen\views\layout.ejs while compiling ejs
```

With the help of stackoverflow I changed the `include` template to:

```
<% include ("partials/nav"); %>
```

This solved the error, but it does not show the `nav` when I run it. And the page source shows a `<nav>`-tag that is empty.

I would appreciate any help.

For the sake of completeness, this is my index.js:

```
"use strict";

const port = 3000;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const homeController = require("./controllers/homeController");
const layouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");

app
  .set("view engine", "ejs")
  .use(
    express.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    })
  )
  .use(express.json())
  .use(layouts)
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Request made to ${req.url}`);
    next();
  })
  .get("/", homeController.sendReqParam)
  .get("/:myname", homeController.sendReqParam)
  .listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
  });
```

Comment: try `<%= include ("partials/nav"); %>`

Comment: This renders the html as text. The browser shows: "<ul> <li>One</li> <li>Two</li> <li>Three</li> </ul>"

Comment: I found the answer thanks to your reply @kaleidawave. When I replace the equals-sign (=) by a minus (-) it does work. SO it's `<%- include ("partials/nav"); %>`

Comment: ah yes my bad, got mixed up between = and -. See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `<%- include ("partials/nav"); %>` to render your partial. The `<%` is just for scripting and control-flow and produces no output, thus you are not seeing anything added to the page. Adding a `-` after `<%` will cause it to output the unescaped value of `include ("partials/nav")`.